# Ranef_pred unable to compute predicted values

Tags: r, graph, error-handling, lme4

I am trying to plot lmer data onto a graph. I am looking at how Unemployment impacts trade volume of wildlife, with Country as a random effect. I have run this exact code 10 other times for similar datasets and it works perfectly, but on 2 of them it wont run. This is the only significant effect in my dataset so I really want a graph to visualise the model.

The code stops running at the Ranef_pred section, where I get this error:

```r
 Error: Unable to compute predicted values with this model. You can try to
  supply a different dataset to the `newdata` argument. This error
  was also raised:
  
  new levels detected in newdata: Greenland, Saint Kitts and Nevis
  
  Bug Tracker:
  https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues"
```

I have no idea what is wrong, as it is exactly the same as other code which has run fine.

My code is:

```
mammals <- read_csv("export csv data by genera/Mammalexportnopoverty.csv")

mammals <- mutate(mammals,
       Logvol = log10(Vol + 0.00001))

unemploymod <- lmer(Logvol ~ Unemployment + (Unemployment | Country), mammals)

summary(unemploymod)
anova(unemploymod)
fixef(unemploymod)


Ranef_pred <- predictions(model = unemploymod, 
                          newdata = mammals,  
                          conf_level = .95,
                          re.form = ~(Unemployment | Country)
                          ) %>% 
  mutate(Log_preds = 10^estimate,
         Log_low = 10^conf.low,
         Log_high = 10^conf.high)



Average_dat <- mammals %>% summarise(Forest = seq(from = min(Forest), to = max(Forest), length.out = 100))

Average_pred <- predictions(unemploymod, 
                          newdata = Average_dat, 
                          conf_level = .95, 
                          re.form = NA 
                          ) %>% 
  mutate(Log_preds = 10^estimate,
         Log_low = 10^conf.low,
         Log_high = 10^conf.high)

ggplot(mammals, aes(Unemployment, Vol)) +
  facet_wrap(~Country) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = Ranef_pred, aes(Unemployment, ymin = Log_low, ymax = Log_high), fill = "cyan4", colour = "cyan4", alpha = .25) +
  geom_line(data = Ranef_pred, aes(Unemployment, Log_preds)) +
  theme_minimal()


ggplot(mammals, aes(Unemployment, Vol)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = Ranef_pred, aes(Unemployment, Log_preds, group = Country), alpha = .40) +
  geom_ribbon(data = Average_pred, aes(Unemployment, y=Log_preds,  ymin = Log_low, ymax = Log_high), fill = "cyan4", colour = "cyan4", alpha = .5) +
  geom_line(data = Average_pred, aes(Unemployment, Log_preds), colour = "darkblue", size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(x = "Unemployment (% population)", y = "Volume traded")
```

I've tried looking this up but can't find the exact problem. I've tried reloading the data, removing the log (but I need the log), and running it in a new script but it hasn't made any difference. I've looked at the bugtracker link but I'm very new to mixed models and cannot see why it isn't running

Comment: There is no reproducible example so it's hard to say for certain, but I think you will most likely solve all your problem by putting all your data in a single df. Use cbind.data.frame() Also, Check for NAs in you dataset and remove rows with them.

Comment: @procerus I'm not sure what you mean by put it all into one df? It already is all in the mammals data frame is it not? Does adding 0.00001 to the log data not remove any NA's also?

Comment: You are right, I didnt read carefully, I missed the part where the problem appears in "ranef_pred" part. Check for NAs in you random effect. Summary(mammals) and see if there are NAs. I spent lot of time dealing with lme4 and the error is usually something obvious and stupid that you forgot that keeps driving you nuts.

Comment: @procerus you were correct about NA's appearing. I had data for the other independent variables for those countries but not for unemployment. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: some of the levels in your prediction data are not present in the fit data. Maybe the Greenland observations were removed by listwise deletion because of missingness?

You can pass the `allow.new.levels` argument to `predictions`. `marginaleffects` will then forward it to the `predict()` method of the `lme4` package. This is documented in `?predictions`.

```r
library(lme4)
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lmer(mpg ~ hp + (1 | cyl), data = mtcars)

nd <- transform(head(mtcars, 2), cyl = 9)

predictions(mod, newdata = nd)
# Error: Unable to compute predicted values with this model. You can try to
#   supply a different dataset to the `newdata` argument. This error was
#   also raised:
#   
#   new levels detected in newdata: 9
#   
#   Bug Tracker:
#   https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues

predictions(mod, newdata = nd, allow.new.levels = TRUE)
# 
#  Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 % cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs
#      21.4       2.43 8.79   <0.001  16.6   26.1   9  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.5  0
#      21.4       2.43 8.79   <0.001  16.6   26.1   9  160 110  3.9 2.88 17.0  0
#  am gear carb
#   1    4    4
#   1    4    4
# 
# Columns: rowid, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, conf.low, conf.high, mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, vs, am, gear, carb
```